# R Many Models Multiple Functions

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr, purrr, lme4

I've written a routine that extracts information from lmer models to compute the ICC and get the LRT from lmerTest's *ranova* function.  What I have below works but I suspect it could be improved by (a) combining the two functions into one and returning a list, but I can't seem to access the list elements with purrr's map function, and (b) using multiple mutate/purrr lines to get all the needed data in one place rather than having to join later.  My code follows using the "Peet" dataset provided in Hox (2002) and available at the UCLA IDRE site:

```
library(foreign)
library(lme4)
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)


#Peet family data described and used in Hox
peet.dat<-read.dta("https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/stata/examples/mlm_ma_hox/peetmis.dta")

names(peet.dat)

#convert to long format
peet.long.dat <- peet.dat %>%
  tidyr::gather(type, score, -family,-sex,-person) %>%
  arrange(type)

names(peet.long.dat)

#need two functions, one for the MLM estimates and the other for
#ranova p-test for variance--merge later by type

aov_model <- function(df) {
  lmr.model <- lmerTest::lmer(score~ 1 + (1|family), data=df)
}

aov_test <- function(df) {
  lmr.model <- lmerTest::lmer(score~ 1 + (1|family), data=df)
  ll.test <- lmerTest::ranova(lmr.model)
}

#get the model estimates
models <- peet.long.dat %>%
  nest(-type) %>%
  mutate(aov_obj = map(data, aov_model),
         summaries = map(aov_obj, broom.mixed::tidy)) %>%
  unnest(summaries, .drop = T) %>%
  select(type, effect, estimate, term) %>%
  filter(effect != "fixed") %>%
  mutate(variance = estimate^2) %>%
  select(-estimate, -effect) %>%
  spread(term, variance) %>%
  rename(group.var = `sd__(Intercept)`, residual = `sd__Observation`) %>%
  mutate(ICC = group.var/(group.var+residual))


models

#get the ranova LRTs
tests <- peet.long.dat %>%
  nest(-type) %>%
  mutate(test_obj = map(data, aov_test),
         test_summaries = map(test_obj, broom.mixed::tidy)) %>%
  unnest(test_summaries, .drop = T) %>%
  filter(!is.na(LRT))

#join estimates with LRT p values
models %>% left_join(tests[c("type","p.value")])
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the key here is to `split()` your data.frame based on the variable `type`:

```r
# convert to list by type
peet.ls <- peet.dat %>%
  tidyr::gather(type, score, -family,-sex,-person) %>%
  split(.$type)

# map to fit models on subsets and return summaries
peet.ls %>%
  map(function(df.x) {
    # fit the model
    lmr_model <- lmerTest::lmer(score~ 1 + (1|family), data = df.x)
    
    #get the model estimates
    mlm_est <- lmr_model %>% 
      broom.mixed::tidy() %>%
      select(effect, estimate, term) %>%
      filter(effect != "fixed") %>%
      mutate(variance = estimate^2) %>%
      select(-estimate, -effect) %>%
      spread(term, variance) %>%
      rename(group.var = `sd__(Intercept)`, 
             residual = `sd__Observation`) %>%
      mutate(ICC = group.var/(group.var+residual))
    
    # get the ranova LRTs & add to other estimates
    mlm_est$p.value <- lmr_model %>%
      lmerTest::ranova() %>%
      broom.mixed::tidy() %>%
      filter(!is.na(LRT)) %>%
      pull(p.value)
  
    # return summaries
    mlm_est
  }) %>%
  # combine data.frames and add the variable 'type'
  bind_rows(.id = "type") %>%
  select(type, everything())
```